# Avoid terminal scroll issue when using zle reset-prompt

Tags: zsh, zle

I use `TMOUT=10` - 10s to update time in prompt so it caused scroll always go back to current prompt. For i.e: If I scroll back serverl pages of output then 10s later, zsh scroll down when prompt was reset.

How to avoid this issue?

Comment: The scroll back upon application output is something you'd have to tell your terminal emulator not to do. For instance, with `xterm`, see the `-si` option (also in `rxvt`) and `scrollTtyOutput` X11 resource

Comment: Not true, zsh reset-prompt draw focus on current prompt, it doesn't cause clear screen but does something in background.

Comment: The point is that without `-si`, `xterm` cancels the scroll when some data is coming from applications running in the terminal. `reset-prompt` rewrites the prompt so sends some data. `zsh` has no visibility and no possible control whatsoever on terminal scrolling, there's nothing it can do.

Comment: If that I use `system32/bash.exe` on windows10. I don't have xterm, don't see any kind of such options in window's properties.

Comment: If that behaviour of the Windows terminal emulator (note that `bash` is not a terminal emulator, it's a shell, I suppose Windows invokes a terminal emulator by itself  when you start `bash`) cannot be disabled, there's little you can do. You could run a terminal-emulator within the terminal emulator like screen or tmux that don't do that and use their scrolling capabilities. I'd expect you'd be able to use `xterm` or other Unix terminal emulator on Windows.

Comment: True, I'm using tmux and with `Prefix + [` - default scroll, I can avoid this issue. still leave unanswered but possible resolved.